# only() method in Python?

Tags: python

I have these lines in Python:

```
page = lxml.html.parse(URL).getroot()
table = only(page.cssselect('table[width=510]'))
```

What is the `only` method doing? I can't find it in the Python docs (though that might just be because it's very hard to search for!)

thanks.

Comment: it's not a built-in method. Probably it's imported.

Comment: `only` isn't a keyword or builtin, so it's coming from somewhere in your application.  Look for any kind of `from foo import *` in your source file and then search those modules for a free `only` function.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `only` built-in function, as you'll see if you type `help(only)` into your Python interpreter.

It must be pulled into the namespace with a `from <module> import <only|*>` instruction in that module. When you find this, you could try importing the module in your Python interpreter and using the `help` function again to find out what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to figure out which module `only` is defined in by examining the `import` statements in your file.  Then look up `only` in the docs for that module.  Or just put a `print only.__module__` in your code and that might print out the module.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it isn't standard. But I'd guess that it fetches the only element from its input, or raises an exception if the input doesn't have exactly one element. E.g.:

```
>>> def only(input):
...     [result] = input
...     return result
... 
>>> only([12])
12
>>> only([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in only
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
>>> only([23, 34])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in only
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`only` is not a built-in function. Is it defined or imported anywhere in the .py file that you have? If not, look for `from somemodule import *`, and then look in each occurrence of `somemodule`.